# Meaning of '{ }' in Excel formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a table in which Tab 1 is listing only those entries from Tab 2 for which a specific criterion is valid via following formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Input!$A:$O;SMALL(IF(Input!$A$1:$A$20000="Yes";ROW(Input!$A$1:$A$20000));ROW(1:1));2));"";INDEX(Input!$A:$O;SMALL(IF(Input!$A$1:$A$20000="Yes";ROW(Input!$A$1:$A$20000));ROW(1:1));4))
```

When reviewing the "function arguments" subwindow, the formula result is indicating the correct result.  However, it does not appear in my table, in which merely a "0" is appearing or just a blank field.

The table is based on an older one (not by myself), in which these features do work. Only difference between the formulas is that in the "old" one, the formula is appearing to start with `{` and end with `}`, whereas when opening the cell both symbols do not appear:

```
{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Input!$A:$K;SMALL(IF(Input!$A$1:$A$20000="Yes";ROW(Input!$A$1:$A$20000));ROW(1:1));2));"";INDEX(Input!$A:$K;SMALL(IF(Input!$A$1:$A$20000="Yes";ROW(Input!$A$1:$A$20000));ROW(1:1));4))}
```

Anyone any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: They're [array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

Comment: In short, these calculate the same function multiple times over a range, and give an array of results. You must confirm by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER.

Answer (score 3):

{} brackets are array formulas see

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx

To enter a formula as an array formula you must do Ctrl+Shift+Enter whilst in the cell